# Why a Muslim should take his hands to sky while praying? Is not God under earth?

Tags: allah, dua

Is there anything about this in Quran?

God exists everywhere. But what is the reason of this?

Quran says:

> وَلِلَّـهِ الْمَشْرِقُ وَالْمَغْرِبُ ۚ فَأَيْنَمَا تُوَلُّوا فَثَمَّ وَجْهُ اللَّـهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ وَاسِعٌ عَلِيمٌ
>
> [[2:115]](http://tanzil.net/#2:115)
>
> And to Allah belongs the east and the west. So wherever you [might] turn, there is the Face of Allah. Indeed, Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing.

Comment: When you say above or below you're thinking in terms of 3 dimensions that we're confined in. I think its important to know that Allah doesn't necessarily have to be bound by the laws of physics that are imposed on our universe. Except for sky, in every other direction you're likely to point at a material object which can cause confusion for some and another reason to differentiate between muslims based on practices. Hence pointing to sky is most logical.

Comment: @HasanKhan that answer qualifies well to be written as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked this question from Imam Ali (S.A.) and he replied this verse in response:

> وَفِي السَّمَاءِ رِزْقُكُمْ وَمَا تُوعَدُونَ
>
> [[51:22]](http://tanzil.net/#51:22) Sahih International

And in the heaven is your provision and whatever you are promised.

This means Allah is everywhere but wheat we ask for it is in Heaven.

Comment: The answer from @Abdullah is correct, Allah is not everywhere, if he was then it would mean he is bound inside his own creation, even inside things that are dirty, which of course is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Allah is not everywhere! Allah is above His seven heavens, above His 'Arsh (Throne), and separated from His creatures, and His creatures are separated from Him. We believe in and confirm all of the attributes of Allah without distorting their meaning.

If Allah is everywhere why then the Qur'anic verses does not read, 'Declare your Rubb, (around you), (below you), or (everywhere)?'

Rather:

Allah says:

> "They fear their Rubb above them." [Qur'an 16:50]

This verse refers to the angels who are above us, and above them is our Rubb, the Blessed, the Exalted.
 Lest anyone be confused, Allah confirms in this verse that He is above the angels who are the residents of the heavens:

> "The Compassionate has rose over the 'Arsh."; [Qur'an 20:2]
>
> And: "And verily, your Rubb is Allah who created the heaven and earth
>   in six days, and then rose over the 'Arsh."; [Qur'an 7:54]

Allah also says:

> "Are you sure that He Who is Above the heaven will not cleave the
>   earth beneath you? Or are you sure that He Who is above the heaven
>   will not send against you a stone-charged hurricane."; [Qur'an
>   67:17,18 ]

We raise our hands to sky knowing Allah is above the Heavens.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments to argue theology. Agree to disagree.

Comment: Don't forget that the earth is round. When we raise our hands above to the sky, we are in the perspective of the others in the other side of earth, "raising" our hands down.

Now, there are different of opinions about these verses. Consider the verse: "And it is He who has made you successors upon the earth and has *raised* some of you *above* others in degrees [of rank] that He may try you through what He has given you. Indeed, your Lord is swift in penalty; but indeed, He is Forgiving and Merciful."

Answer (score 1):

Because upwards represents highness. This is also why bosses use higher chairs and give their clients/guests lower ones.