# Can we see Allah in the hereafter, the same way we see the other things? (Sunni view)

Tags: allah, sunni

Can we see Allah in the Hereafter, the same way we see the other things?

**EDIT**

@owari commented the link to [this page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/do-shiites-deny-seeing-allah-on-the-day-of-judgement-if-yes-why) that has already listed the Shia references from Quran and Hadith that watching Allah by eyes is impossible before or after death, including:

> لاَّ تُدْرِكُهُ الأَبْصَارُ وَهُوَ يُدْرِكُ الأَبْصَارَ وَهُوَ
>   اللَّطِيفُ الْخَبِيرُ - الانعام 103
>
> وَلَمَّا جَاءَ مُوسَى لِمِيقَاتِنَا وَكَلَّمَهُ رَبُّهُ قَالَ رَبِّ
>   أَرِنِي أَنظُرْ إِلَيْكَ قَالَ لَنْ تَرَانِي - الأعراف:143

Also Shia interprets ناظرة in ayah below as *waiting* rewards from the Lord:

> وجُوهٌ يَوْمَئِذٍ ناضِرَةٌ إِلى‏ رَبِّها ناظِرَةٌ - القيامة 22 ,23

So I narrow down this question to the ideas of Sunni brothers - to prevent duplicate question:

- What is the most agreed idea of Sunni scholars about watching Allah in the Hereafter?
- Do all Sunni scholars have the same idea about this?
- What is the reasoning behind their ideas?
- If some (or all) believe we are able to see Allah in the Hereafter, do they mean seeing him the same way we see any other object now?

Comment: You may find your answer [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2826/584).

Comment: @owari +1 Thanks, I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***What is the most agreed idea of Sunni scholars about watching Allah in the Hereafter?***

It is confirmed by the Quran, Sunnah, and consensus of the Pious Salaf that the believers will see Allah with their eyes on the day of the Judgement.

***Do all Sunni scholars have the same idea about this?***

Yes.

***What is the reasoning behind their ideas?***

Evidence for any belief about Allah is from Qur'an and Sunnah. While, in [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2826/38) the verses which are evidence for this belief is quoted, it is also proven by overwhelming number of Sahih Hadiths. I quote some of them here (emphasis mine):

> Suhaib reported the Apostle (may peace be upon him) saying: When
> those deserving of Paradise would enter Paradise, the Blessed and the
> Exalted would ask: Do you wish Me to give you anything more? They
> would say: Hast Thou not brightened our faces? Hast Thou not made us
> enter Paradise and saved us from Fire? He (the narrator) said: He
> **(God) would lift the veil, and of things given to them nothing would
> he dearer to them than the sight of their Lord, the Mighty and the
> Glorious.**
>
> حَدَّثَنَا عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عُمَرَ بْنِ مَيْسَرَةَ، قَالَ
> حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ مَهْدِيٍّ، حَدَّثَنَا حَمَّادُ بْنُ
> سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ ثَابِتٍ الْبُنَانِيِّ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ
> أَبِي لَيْلَى، عَنْ صُهَيْبٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ
> ‏ "‏ إِذَا دَخَلَ أَهْلُ الْجَنَّةِ الْجَنَّةَ - قَالَ - يَقُولُ
> اللَّهُ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى تُرِيدُونَ شَيْئًا أَزِيدُكُمْ
> فَيَقُولُونَ أَلَمْ تُبَيِّضْ وُجُوهَنَا أَلَمْ تُدْخِلْنَا الْجَنَّةَ
> وَتُنَجِّنَا مِنَ النَّارِ - قَالَ - فَيَكْشِفُ الْحِجَابَ فَمَا
> أُعْطُوا شَيْئًا أَحَبَّ إِلَيْهِمْ مِنَ النَّظَرِ إِلَى رَبِّهِمْ
> عَزَّ وَجَلَّ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ [[Sahih Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/muslim:181a)

and

> Narrated Qais:
>
> Jarir said, "We were with the Prophet and he looked at the
> moon--full-moon--and said, **'Certainly you will see your Lord as you
> see this moon and you will have no trouble in seeing Him.** So if you
> can avoid missing (through sleep or business, etc.) a prayer before
> the sunrise (Fajr) and a prayer before sunset (Asr), you must do so.'
> He then recited Allah's Statement: And celebrate the praises Of your
> Lord before the rising of the sun and before (its) setting." (50.39)
> Isma`il said, "Offer those prayers and do not miss them."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا الْحُمَيْدِيُّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا مَرْوَانُ بْنُ
> مُعَاوِيَةَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، عَنْ قَيْسٍ، عَنْ جَرِيرٍ،
> قَالَ كُنَّا عِنْدَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَنَظَرَ إِلَى
> الْقَمَرِ لَيْلَةً ـ يَعْنِي الْبَدْرَ ـ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ إِنَّكُمْ
> سَتَرَوْنَ رَبَّكُمْ كَمَا تَرَوْنَ هَذَا الْقَمَرَ لاَ تُضَامُّونَ
> فِي رُؤْيَتِهِ، فَإِنِ اسْتَطَعْتُمْ أَنْ لاَ تُغْلَبُوا عَلَى صَلاَةٍ
> قَبْلَ طُلُوعِ الشَّمْسِ وَقَبْلَ غُرُوبِهَا فَافْعَلُوا ‏"‏‏.‏ ثُمَّ
> قَرَأَ ‏{‏وَسَبِّحْ بِحَمْدِ رَبِّكَ قَبْلَ طُلُوعِ الشَّمْسِ وَقَبْلَ
> الْغُرُوبِ‏}‏‏.‏ قَالَ إِسْمَاعِيلُ افْعَلُوا لاَ تَفُوتَنَّكُمْ‏.‏
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/31)

There are many hadiths regarding the same event.

***If some (or all) believe we are able to see Allah in the Hereafter, do they mean seeing him the same way we see any other object now?***

Your doubt regarding how we will see Him (Subhanahu wa ta'ala) is cleared by the statement of the Prophet(salallahu alayhi wassalam) in several hadith:

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said: "Do
> you crowd one another in order to see the moon on the night of a full
> moon? Do you crowd one another in order to see the sun?" They said:
> "No." He said: **"So verily, **you shall see your Lord as you see the moon
> on the night of a full moon**, you shall not crowd one another to see
> Him."** ([Sahih](http://sunnah.com/urn/678600))

That we will see Him with our own eyes:

> Narrated Jarir bin `Abdullah:
>
> The Prophet said, "You will definitely see your Lord with your own
> eyes." [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/urn/69870)

And you will have no trouble seeing Him:

> Abu Hurairah said : The people asked : Messenger of Allah! Shall we
> see our lord, the Exalted, on the Day of resurrection? He replied : Do
> you feel any trouble in seeing the sun at noon when it is not in the
> cloud? They said: No. He asked : **Do you feel any trouble in seeing the
> moon on the night when it is full and not in the cloud? They replied:
> No. He said: By him in whose hand my soul is, you will not feel any
> trouble in seeing him except as much as you feel in seeing any of
> them.** [[Sunan Abi Dawood]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/135)

You can read several other Ahadeeth and statements of the Salaf and Scholars of the Ummah regarding the belief [here.](http://www.as-salaf.com/article.php?aid=77&lang=en) It is a compendium of all the evidences.

Comment: +1 for the complete and referenced answer

Comment: "Do all Sunni scholars have the same idea about this?
Yes" 
 This is false.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference to seeing Allah after death, but only those who enter paradise.

In an uncited commentary on [HadithADay.org](http://hadithaday.org/hadith-qudsi-collection/had-149-%E2%80%93-seeing-allah-in-paradise/), it is said that,

> The blessings which Allah bestows upon His slaves cannot be counted. Allah has singled 
>   out the believers for additional blessings in this world, as He has blessed them with 
>   Islam, and chosen them to be guided by the Qur’an, and He will bless them exclusively in 
>   Paradise with the greatest blessing that He can bestow, which is the honour of looking 
>   upon His holy Face in Paradise, as He says (interpretation of the meaning): “Some faces 
>   that Day shall be Naadirah (shining and radiant). Looking at their Lord (Allah)” [[al-Qiyaamah :22-23](http://quran.com/75/22-23)]

Comment: I updated the question to prevent duplication. Would you please update the answer accordingly?