# Name in the hereafter

Tags: allah, jannah, islamic-basis, day-of-judgement

Salam alaikum. I am wondering what our names will be in jannah for example some people have several names because of culture reasons like mine for example when I was first born it was Zahra, then my parents changed it to uzma and now I have both uzma and urooj az my name. Which one would I be called by in the other world. Does anyone know?

Comment: It can be whatever you want.

Comment: Really? I had heard it would be your birth name but wasn't sure

Comment: Quran 50:35 - "There they will have whatever they desire, and with Us is ˹even˺ more."
https://quran.com/50?startingVerse=35




Quran 41:31 - "We are your supporters in this worldly life and in the Hereafter. There you will have whatever your souls desire, and there you will have whatever you ask for"
https://quran.com/41?startingVerse=31

Comment: The only thing that is limited in heaven is the amount of time an inhabitant of heaven can see Allah's face. The higher level you are, the more time you get to see Allah's face.

Comment:  Why is it limited

Comment: Could I please have a reference for this

Comment: It is controversial among different sects that whether they can see Allah or not ( let far go of any limited time) and hence depends upon your interpretation of Qur'an. For example , see this : 
https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2826/51089

Comment: @Zaraaa Seeing Allah's face is the greatest pleasure anyone can have. So those who did better in this life and are in higher levels get to see his face more.

Comment: Thanks inshallah we are amongst the pleased so we can see Allah SWT